# How to append from multiple dictionaries in a List to another list with specific parts of the "inner" dictionary?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, append

I've got dictionaries in a list:

```
fit_statstest = [{'activities-heart': [{'dateTime': '2018-02-01',
'value': {'customHeartRateZones': [],
 'heartRateZones': [{'caloriesOut': 2119.9464,
   'max': 96,
   'min': 30,
   'minutes': 1232,
   'name': 'Out of Range'},
  {'caloriesOut': 770.2719,
   'max': 134,
   'min': 96,
   'minutes': 120,
   'name': 'Fat Burn'},
  {'caloriesOut': 0,
   'max': 163,
   'min': 134,
   'minutes': 0,
   'name': 'Cardio'},
  {'caloriesOut': 0,
   'max': 220,
   'min': 163,
   'minutes': 0,
   'name': 'Peak'}],
 'restingHeartRate': 64}}],
'activities-heart-intraday': {'dataset': [{'time': '00:00:00', 'value': 57},
{'time': '00:00:10', 'value': 56},
{'time': '00:00:20', 'value': 59},
{'time': '00:00:35', 'value': 59},
{'time': '02:54:10', 'value': 85},
{'time': '02:54:20', 'value': 71},
{'time': '02:54:30', 'value': 66},
...],'datasetInterval': 1,
'datasetType': 'second'}},
{'activities-heart': [{'dateTime': '2018-02-02',
'value': {'customHeartRateZones': [],
 'heartRateZones': [{'caloriesOut': 2200.61802,
   'max': 96,
   'min': 30,
   'minutes': 1273,
   'name': 'Out of Range'},
  {'caloriesOut': 891.9588,
   'max': 134,
   'min': 96,
   'minutes': 133,
   'name': 'Fat Burn'},
  {'caloriesOut': 35.8266,
   'max': 163,
   'min': 134,
   'minutes': 3,
   'name': 'Cardio'},
  {'caloriesOut': 0,
   'max': 220,
   'min': 163,
   'minutes': 0,
   'name': 'Peak'}],
 'restingHeartRate': 67}}],
'activities-heart-intraday': {'dataset': [{'time': '00:00:10', 'value': 80},
{'time': '00:00:15', 'value': 79},
{'time': '00:00:20', 'value': 74},
{'time': '00:00:25', 'value': 72},
{'time': '03:04:10', 'value': 61},
{'time': '03:04:25', 'value': 61},
{'time': '03:04:40', 'value': 61},
...],
'datasetInterval': 1,
'datasetType': 'second'}}]
```

I'm trying to append the 'time': 'hh:mm:ss' and 'value': Int to a DataFrame.

This is how I did it for a single dictionary (which worked like a charm):

```
time_list = []
val_list = []
for i in fit_statsHR['activities-heart-intraday']['dataset']:
    val_list.append(i['value'])
    time_list.append(i['time'])
```

And this is how I tried doing it for the multi-level dictionary list:

```
time_test = []
val_test = []
for i in fit_statstest:
    val_test.append(i['activities-heart-intraday']['dataset']['value'])
    time_test.append(i['activities-heart-intraday']['dataset']['time'])
heartdftest = pd.DataFrame({'Heart Rate':val_test,'Time':time_test})
```

I get this error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str; and am not quite sure how to go about solving this problem.

I tried using the .copy() method but had no joy with that either.

UPDATE:
@Phydeaux: Cheers for this! I tried this:

```
time_test = []
val_test = []
j = np.arange(0,len(fit_statstest))

for i in fit_statstest[j]['activities-heart-intraday']['dataset']:
    val_test.append(i['value'])
    time_test.append(i['time'])
```

I get this error now:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-184-f3e7484e1cfc> in <module>()
  3 j = np.arange(0,len(fit_statstest))
  4 
----> 5 for i in fit_statstest[j]['activities-heart-intraday']['dataset']:
  6     val_test.append(i['value'])
  7     time_test.append(i['time'])

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index. Not sure if I'm going in the right track though!

Answer (score 1):

`i['activities-heart-intraday']['dataset']` is a list containing multiple dictionaries, each of which has a `'value'` attribute. You are trying to treat this list as if it were a dictionary, which is what causes the exception you are getting.

You had the right idea with your code for the single dictionary. You need to loop through the list and do something with each item.

---

**Edit:** you can't directly use `np.arange` to index a list like that, as the exception says. What were you expecting that to do?

Try this:

```
time_test = []
val_test = []

# use descriptive names for your loop indices that give a hint about what they represent
for day in fit_statstest:
    for entry in day['activities-heart-intraday']['dataset']:
        time_test.append(entry['time'])
        val_test.append(entry['value'])
```

Comment: Cheers for this! I tried this:
time_test = []
val_test = []
j = np.arange(0,29)
for i in fit_statstest[j]['activities-heart-intraday']['dataset']:
    val_test.append(i['value'])
    time_test.append(i['time'])
heartdftest = pd.DataFrame({'Heart Rate':val_test,'Time':time_test})

I get this error now: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index.

Not sure if I'm going in the right track though!

Comment: @Vash Can you edit that into the question (formatted)? It's a bit difficult to read in a comment. Also, in general it's helpful if you include the full text of the exception (especially the line on which it occurs).

Comment: sorry about the mess! I've added the code and error to the question now. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution via a single list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd

time_values = [(d['time'], d['value']) for day in fit_statstest \
               for d in day['activities-heart-intraday']['dataset']]

df = pd.DataFrame(time_values, columns=['time', 'value'])
```

**Result**

```
        time  value
0   00:00:00     57
1   00:00:10     56
2   00:00:20     59
3   00:00:35     59
4   02:54:10     85
5   02:54:20     71
6   02:54:30     66
7   00:00:10     80
8   00:00:15     79
9   00:00:20     74
10  00:00:25     72
11  03:04:10     61
12  03:04:25     61
13  03:04:40     61
```